# Alternative to $(window).scroll for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a web page with a tabbed navigation bar that is a little ways down the page. The page is responsive, so heights and widths of the window are subject to change. My code works fine in desktop environments, but when I pull it up on my iphone or ipad, the `$(window).scroll` function is slow to respond. I'll scroll down, and only when the screen stops scrolling, will my function happen. It makes my fixed nav delay to appear or disappear. Any suggestions? Code samples below:

HTML:

```
<div id="retail-nav">
                <div id="navwrap">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="retail-tab-1"><a class="active"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i> <?php the_field(tab_1);?></a></li>
                        <li id="retail-tab-2"><a><i class="icon-lock"></i> <?php the_field(tab_2);?></a></li>
                        <li id="retail-tab-3"><a><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i> <?php the_field(tab_3);?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="retail-nav-float">
                <div id="navwrap-float">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="retail-tab-1-float"><a class="active"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i> <?php the_field(tab_1);?></a></li>
                        <li id="retail-tab-2-float"><a><i class="icon-lock"></i> <?php the_field(tab_2);?></a></li>
                        <li id="retail-tab-3-float"><a><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i> <?php the_field(tab_3);?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var navHeight = jQuery('#retail-nav').offset().top;
                jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                        jQuery('#retail-nav-float').css('display', 'inline');
                    }else{
                        jQuery('#retail-nav-float').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                });
```

CSS:

```
 #retail-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #494949;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#retail-nav-float{
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #494949;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    display: none;
}
#navwrap, #navwrap-float{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1012px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -13px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For phone & tablet, you will have to add `touchmove` events.

e.g.

```
element.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
```

This page goes in depth about it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: I've been trying to wrap my head around this, but I can't figure out how to implement this as an that can effectively replace the scroll event on desktop...